# (Qt 5.7.0) How to add a horizontal spacer in toolBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.7

I have a QtoolBar in my mainwindow. This toolBar have several QActions. I need some of this Actions to stay in the left side of the toolBar and some o them to stay at the right side.

How do I make them separeted?

I don't see any reason for more details inn this question but if necessary I will add them.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using two QToolBars put into a QHBoxLayout with a QSpacerItem in between?

Comment: @Ignitor Well, that is a pretty good ideia. The only problem now is that there is a visual separation between both QToolBars. It ain't the best solution but works fine. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
// add left Actions
QAction* action1 = ui.toolBar->addAction(/* ... */);

// Spacer
QWidget* spacer = new QWidget();
spacer->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
ui.toolBar->addWidget(spacer);

// add right Actions
QAction* action2 = ui.toolBar->addAction(/* ... */);
```

Between my left and right actions, I've added a QWidget that separates them. Crucial for this is QSizePolicy :: Expanding

Comment: Please describe a little bit your solution, and don't just dump code as an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer